# How do I set up add, delete, update and view permissions for a particular model instance?

Tags: python, django, permissions, django-admin, authorization

I am a Python and Django newbie  working on a Django app and  I have a requirement in which I have to manage permissions for model instance Foo in my Django. There are other model instances available but the permissions only apply for foo.

I have overridden `has_add_permission`, `has_delete_permission` in my FooAdmin class but nothing seems to be working.

Requirement:

1. Add Foo object: The user must be a super admin
2. Delete Foo object: The user must be a super admin
3. Edit existing Foo object: The user must belong to ldap group 'foo-edit'. If the user belongs to this group, then he/she can only edit one field (building) (Not Yet Implemented)
4. View Foo: If the user belongs to ldap group 'foo-access', then the user has only view rights. (To Be Investigated)
5. If any other model instance is to be added, updated, deleted or modified, then rules 1 to 4 don't apply.

My implementation:

```
class FooAdmin(ModelAdmin):
  ...
  ...
  ...
  def has_add_permission(self, request):
    permissions = self.opts.app_label + '.' + self.opts.get_add_permission()
    # Other objects are fine.
    user = request.user
    if (user.has_perm('survey.add_foo') and user.is_authenticated
        and user.is_superuser):
      return True
    return False

  def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    permissions = self.opts.app_label + '.' + self.opts.get_delete_permission()
    user = request.user
    if (user.has_perm('survey.delete_foo') and user.is_authenticated
        and user.is_superuser):
      return True
    return False
```

Issue:

1. I can create another instance of type Bar but can not delete what I have just created. This is not a problem with instances of type FooBar. BarAdmin implementation does not have any code that manages permissions as is the case of FooBarAdmin implementation.

   Is there a way to resolve this issue and make Bar and FooBar deletable again?
2. How do I implement required # 3 and 4? I can override has_change_permission method to determine if the person has change permissions. How do I give the user editing rights for only one field.

   Django does not seem to support view only permissions. I can create has_view_permission(self, request) and get_model_perms(self, request) and other places? But I am not sure how to implement this though. I have been looking through the Django [source code](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/options.py) but can't think of anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of Googling and random hacks, I have able to come up with a solution. I don't know what the protocol is to answer to your question.

1. Create a Middle ware implementation (threadlocals.py) that stores the user information in a thread local object.

   ```
   try:
     from threading import local
   except ImportError:
     from django.utils._threading_local import local

   _thread_locals = local()
   def get_current_user():
     return getattr(_thread_locals, 'user', None)

   class ThreadLocals(object):
     """Middleware that gets various objects from the request object and
     saves them in thread local storage."""

     def process_request(self, request):
       _thread_locals.user = getattr(request, 'user', None)
   ```
2. Create an authorization utility module that will check for permissions.

   ```
   import ldap  
   from django.contrib.auth.models import User    
   from myapp.middleware import threadlocals

   def can_edit():
     user_obj = threadlocals.get_current_user()
     if user_obj and (is_superadmin(user_obj.username) or \
         is_part_of_group(user_obj.username, 'foo-edit')):
       return True
     return False

   def can_edit_selectively():
     user = threadlocals.get_current_user()
     if (user and not user.is_superuser and
         is_part_of_group(user.username, 'foo-edit')):
       return True
     return False

   def can_view_only():
     user_obj = threadlocals.get_current_user()
     if (user_obj and not user_obj.is_superuser and
         is_part_of_group(user_obj.username, 'foo-access') and
         not is_part_of_group(user_obj.username, 'foo-edit')):
       return True
     return False

   def has_add_foo_permission():
     user = threadlocals.get_current_user()
     if (user and user.has_perm('survey.add_foo') and user.is_authenticated
         and user.is_superuser):
       return True
     return False

   def has_delete_foo_permission():
     user = threadlocals.get_current_user()
     if (user and user.has_perm('survey.delete_foo') and user.is_authenticated
         and user.is_superuser):
       return True
     return False

   def is_superadmin(logged_in_user):
      admin = False
      try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=logged_in_user)
        if user.is_superuser:
          admin = True
        except User.DoesNotExist:
          pass
     return admin

   def is_part_of_group(user, group):
     try:
       user_obj = User.objects.get(username=user)
       if user_obj.groups.filter(name=group):
         return True
     except User.DoesNotExist:
       pass
     conn = ldap.open("ldap.corp.mycompany.com")
     conn.simple_bind_s('', '')
     base = "ou=Groups,dc=mycompany,dc=com"
     scope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
     filterstr = "cn=%s" % group
     retrieve_attributes = None
     try:
       ldap_result_id = conn.search_s(base, scope, filterstr, retrieve_attributes)
       if ldap_result_id:
         results = ldap_result_id[0][1]
         return user in results['memberUid']
     except ldap.LDAPError:
       pass
     return False
   ```
3. Set up Admin. In the actions, the permissions are evaluated. Also if the user does not have delete permissions, then the action 'delete Foo' is not available.

   ```
   class FooAdmin(ModelAdmin):

     ...

     def get_actions(self, request):
       actions = super(FooAdmin, self).get_actions(request)
       delete_permission = self.has_delete_permission(request)
       if actions and not delete_permission:
         del actions['delete_selected']
       return actions

     def has_add_permission(self, request):
       return auth_utils.has_add_foo_permission()

     def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
       return auth_utils.has_delete_foo_permission()

     ....
   ```
4. Make changes to **init** function in the implementation of ModelForm

   ```
    class FooForm(ModelForm):

      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.can_view_only = (auth_utils.can_view_only() and
                              not auth_utils.can_edit_selectively())
        self.can_edit_selectively = (auth_utils.can_edit_selectively() or
                                     auth_utils.can_view_only())
        if self.can_edit_selectively:
          ... Set the widget attributes to read only.

        # If the user has view only rights, then disable edit rights for building id.
        if self.can_view_only:
          self.fields['buildingid'].widget = forms.widgets.TextInput()
          self.fields['buildingid'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
        elif (auth_utils.can_edit() or auth_utils.can_edit_selectively()):
          self.fields['buildingid'].widget=forms.Select(choices=
                                                   utils.get_table_values('building'))
   ```
5. I also had to disable the actions that modified the submit line.

   ```
   def submit_edit_selected_row(context):
     opts = context['opts']
     change = context['change']
     is_popup = context['is_popup']
     save_as = context['save_as']
     if opts.object_name.lower() != 'foo':
       has_delete = (not is_popup and context['has_delete_permission']
                     and (change or context['show_delete']))
       has_save_as_new = not is_popup and change and save_as
       has_save_and_add_another = (context['has_add_permission'] and
                                   not is_popup and (not save_as or context['add']))
       has_save_and_continue = (context['has_add_permission'] and
                                not is_popup and (not save_as or context['add']))
       has_save = True
     else:
       has_delete = auth_utils.has_delete_pop_permission()
       has_save_as_new = auth_utils.has_add_pop_permission()
       has_save_and_add_another = auth_utils.has_add_pop_permission()
       has_save_and_continue = (auth_utils.can_edit() or
                                auth_utils.can_edit_selectively())
       has_save = auth_utils.can_edit() or auth_utils.can_edit_selectively()
     return {
       'onclick_attrib': (opts.get_ordered_objects() and change
                             and 'onclick="submitOrderForm();"' or ''),
       'show_delete_link': has_delete,
       'show_save_as_as_new': has_save_as_new,
       'show_save_and_add_another': has_save_and_add_another,
       'show_save_and_continue': has_save_and_continue,
       'is_popup': is_popup,
       'show_save': has_save
      }
   register.inclusion_tag('admin/submit_line.html', takes_context=True) (submit_edit_selected_row)
   ```
6. I had to modify extend the admin template. The rest remains the same.

   ```
   {% if save_on_top %} {% submit_edit_selected_row %} {% endif}
   ```